# How to assign global variables with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, global-variables

Here I've given a small example of the problem I'm facing with global variables and AsyncTasks. I've gone and read in data from a file and assigned that data to a string and in the onPostExecute() method I assigned that string to the global variable. However when I assign the TextView with the "aString" variable, the output is still "nothing".

I know that if you do the TextView assigning in the onPostExecute() method it works however what if I want to use the data in methods outside of the AsyncTask.

Can someone please help with this, I think I'm not getting something?

```
public class GoodAsync extends Activity{

    TextView tv;
    String aString = "nothing";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.asynctasks);

        new AsyncTasker().execute();

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.async_view);
        tv.setText(aString);

    }

    private class AsyncTasker extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            AssetManager am = GoodAsync.this.getAssets();
            String string = "";
            try {
                // Code that reads a file and stores it in the string variable

                return string;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            aString = result;
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to do it like this:

```
public class GoodAsync extends Activity{

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.asynctasks);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.async_view);
    new AsyncTasker().execute();
}

    public void setTextView (String text) {
       tv.setText(text);
    }

    private class AsyncTasker extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        ....

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setTextView(result);
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution than using get() which will cause your UI to freeze if your task takes more than a split second.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your AsyncTask is executing in time?

e.g You are doing this:

```
new AsyncTasker().execute();
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.async_view);
tv.setText(aString);
```

This sets the task going but then immediately sets the value of the TextView to the aString variable.

The AsyncTask is most likely still executing at this point so aString only gets a value other than "nothing" after the code has executed.

Answer (score -1):

You are not waiting for your asynctask to finish..you can do it like this..

```
new AsyncTasker().execute().get();
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.async_view);
tv.setText(aString);
```

Comment: Oh right, I see. So the above code will wait until the AsyncTask has completed, get the ArrayList<String> with the .get() method then set it, am I correct?

Comment: not exactly...get() is basically used to wait for a thread to complete ..however, this is not a good practice to use .get() in your main UI thread, because it cause your UI to freeze..so better you should set the value to your textview in onPostExecute()...

Comment: @Vikram Please do not post such an advise and then use a comment that states its not a good practice to follow my advice. Using `get()` on an AsynTask is a contradiction of this AsyncTask!

Comment: @Baschi: I know that, but the asker has defined that case where he is aware of using onPostBackground() approach...i wrote that because may be he has some specific scenario or looking for an alternate way to do so...and yes, to make him aware of things is also necessary...:)